# TypeScript error: Type 'void' is not assignable to type 'boolean'

Tags: typescript

I am having a TypeScript error:

> Argument of type '(element: Conversation) => void' is not assignable to parameter of type '(value: Conversations, index: number, obj: Conversation[]) => boolean'. Type 'void' is not assignable to type 'boolean'.

This is my schema:

```
export class Conversation {
  constructor(
    public id: number,
    public dateTime: Date,
    public image: string,
    public isUnread: boolean,
    public title: string
  ) {}
}
```

And this is my code

```
// Mark as read also in data store
this.dataStore.data.find((element) => {
  if (element.id === conversationId) {
    element.isUnread = true;
    // Push the updated list of conversations into the observable stream
    this.observer.next(this.dataStore.data);
  }
});
```

What does this error mean?

Answer (score 50, accepted):

It means that the callback function you passed to `this.dataStore.data.find` should return a boolean and have 3 parameters, two of which can be optional:

- value: Conversations
- *index: number*
- *obj: Conversation[]*

However, your callback function does not return anything (returns void). You should pass a callback function with the correct return value:

```
this.dataStore.data.find((element, index, obj) => {
    // ...

    return true; // or false
});
```

or:

```
this.dataStore.data.find(element => {
    // ...

    return true; // or false
});
```

Reason why it's this way: the function you pass to the `find` method is called a *predicate*. The predicate here defines a boolean outcome based on conditions defined in the function itself, so that the `find` method can determine which value to *find*.

In practice, this means that the predicate is called for each item in `data`, and the first item in `data` for which your predicate returns `true` is the value returned by `find`.

Answer (score 11):

Your code is passing a function as an argument to `find`.  That function takes an `element` argument (of type `Conversation`) and returns `void` (meaning there is no return value).  TypeScript describes this as `(element: Conversation) => void'`

What TypeScript is saying is that the `find` function doesn't expect to receive a function that takes a Conversation and returns void.  It expects a function that takes a `Conversations`, a `number` and a `Conversation` array, and that this function should return a `boolean`.

So bottom line is that you either need to change your code to pass in the values to `find` correctly, or else you need to provide an overload to the definition of `find` in your definition file that accepts a `Conversation` and returns `void`.